# Am I using search wrong?

Tags: discussion, search

I am sure a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28168231/823393) has been asked and answered before so I want to find that.

A search on SO for:

> [java] exception as flow control

Gives me a top hit of [Java: Exceptions as control flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546514/java-exceptions-as-control-flow) and a 5 score so I vote to close as duplicate with that reference.

Sadly a little more research unearths [Why not use exceptions as regular flow of control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control) with a 100+ score - what am I doing wrong when searching for duplicates?

Wouldn't it make sense to boost the weight of an answer through it vote count? If that is already the case then what should I do to maximise the chance that the best version of the duplicate question comes to the top.

Comment: not familiar with the topic: [this one?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15542859)

Comment: I have noted that the second one have more votes, but the author didn't set a accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search for [java], you're limiting to questions tagged with the Java tag. The second question you posted doesn't have the Java tag so it wouldn't have shown up in your initial search.

Comment: Good point - I hadn't noticed that.